# Play Framework + Intellij sqlite configuration

Tags: sqlite, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, database-connection

I'm learning how to use the play framework and I wanted to connect my application to a sqlite database using Xerial.

So this is my application.config:
The database is in the project's main folder, so that's why I just stated the name.

```
application.baseUrl="http://localhost:9000"

db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:DB_NAME"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS


# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

evolutionplugin=enabled
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
# ebean.default="models.*"

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

This is my build.sbt:

```
import play.Play.autoImport._
import PlayKeys._

name := """PROJECT NAME"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

libraryDependencies += "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1-2"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final" // replace by your jpa implementation
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Every time run my application it trows an exception regarding the connection to the database, I'll print the stack trace:

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
  while locating play.api.db.DBApiProvider
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for parameter 0 at play.db.DefaultDBApi.<init>(DefaultDBApi.java:28)
  at play.db.DefaultDBApi.class(DefaultDBApi.java:28)
  while locating play.db.DefaultDBApi
  while locating play.db.DBApi
    for field at play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider.dbApi(DBModule.java:61)
  while locating play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.java:40):
Binding(interface play.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to ProviderTarget(play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider@60695fbb)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:984)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies$$FastClassByGuice$$2a7177aa.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Exception during pool initialization]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:1048)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:69)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:124)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:122)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:143)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:139)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:542)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:441)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:540)
    ... 81 more

2) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
  while locating play.api.db.DBApiProvider
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for field at play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider.dbApi(DBModule.scala:80)
  while locating play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.api.db.DBModule$$anonfun$namedDatabaseBindings$1.apply(DBModule.scala:34):
Binding(interface play.api.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider@7a508325)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:984)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies$$FastClassByGuice$$2a7177aa.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Exception during pool initialization]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:1048)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:69)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:124)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:122)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:143)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:139)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:542)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:441)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:540)
    ... 70 more
```

I'm following all the directives on [play framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaDatabase) on how to interact with a db file but I cant manage to get a connection with it!!

I tried every possible solution on the internet but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Just to end it up, maybe it could make some difference: I'm using even the Java Persistence Unit. This is the set up, maybe I did something wrong there that is denying me the access to the DB.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

From Intellij I generated the Persistance Mapping from the Database Schema in order to generate my model classes.

I'm feeling lost :S 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: May be this is common to [A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickFAQ#A-binding-to-play.api.db.DBApi-was-already-configured): JDBC driver imported twice.

Comment: Just to know: where exactly should I remove the JDBC Driver? 
removing it from the built.sbt didn't solve my problem. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: I did not work with sqlite, but when i used `slick`, i have error because of `jdbc` and `slick jdbc` drivers conflict. try remove `javaJdbc`

Comment: So, just to end my post: I haven't found a solution for my problem, so I just decided to switch to Ebean and now I'm working with a "h2" DB.

Comment: Try slick or anorm. They are not ORM, but comfortable instruments.